# How to combine two XPath expressions?

Tags: xpath, nodes, concatenation

I have two XPath expressions that I need to combine.

- First XPath is:

`(//div[@class="filtername"])`

This returns "**New York Hotels**" for example.

- Second XPath is:

`(//div[@class="filternumber"])`

This returns “**100**” for example.

So when combining the two expressions I want the result to look like this: "**New York Hotels 100**"

How do I achieve this?

I think I need to use the concat function but I don’t know how to use it.

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both XPath-1.0 expression each yield only one result, you can use the following `fn:concat` expression:

```
concat(//div[@class="filtername"], ' ', //div[@class="filternumber"])
```

This should return "New York Hotels 100".
(But without an XML file, this cannot be verified by us).

Comment: zx485, thank you for your reply.

That expression didn’t work, unfortunately. Also, when testing it with an XPath tester the expression gives an error.

Here’s the URL of one of my web pages that I’m trying to extract data:
[https://www.jollytur.com/antalya-otelleri].

Here are the two XPath expressions I’m going to use:
1) `(//span[@class="nameFilter"])`
This returns “**Olimpos**” for example.
2) `(//span[@class=“count”])`
This returns “**1**” for example.

So when combining the two expressions I need the result to look like this: "**Olimpos 1**"

Comment: @TheOptimizer: zx485's XPath is fine, other than not including a string with a single space character to provide the requested separation between the two selected strings. Such a modification is trivial for you to make, and there is no syntactic problem with the provided XPath expression.  Double check your verification attempt.

Comment: Using `string(//div[@class="filtre-item result-filter-wrap active"]//label)` could also be an option. Be careful with your second XPath, since it contains right double quotation marks instead of quotation marks.

Comment: Some "XPath testers" will only handle XPath expressions that return node-sets, whereas this one returns a string. However, telling us that something "gives an error" without telling us what error it gives makes it pretty much impossible to help you.

Comment: zx485, E.Wiest, thank you both for providing XPath expressions. They both worked perfectly.